# Following Yolo Pose Tutorial- Facing Issue

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception, yolov8

I am following this tutorial https://github.com/computervisioneng/pose-detection-keypoints-estimation-yolov8

I am replacing with my own data, but either way I recieve the same error. The issue is when I try to convert my annotated images from CVAT to YOLO using the code provided in the file "CVATtoCocoKeyPoints.py" file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ishaangupta/Downloads/main/assderp/jorgensen-v5/pose-detection-keypoints-estimation-yolov8/CVAT_to_cocoKeypoints.py", line 22, in <module>
    bbox = image.getElementsByTagName('box')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that the method, **getElementsByTagName()**, will look for the tags denominated **box**, so, the most logical answer with the information you've submitted will be, that your data doesn't poses that tag.

This error should be handled, because probably there are cases where the data submitted doesn't have that property or others...

Can you upload an example of your data?

Comment: Sure, here is a piece of my XML file for one image:

  <image id="0" name="AN15093001_14ft_MALE_01frame79.jpg" width="1284" height="583">
    <box label="FullBody" source="manual" occluded="0" xtl="219.00" ytl="147.13" xbr="1075.99" ybr="350.09" rotation="8.70" z_order="0">
    </box>
    <points label="FullBody" source="manual" occluded="0" points="219.80,211.21;1066.51,341.73;466.34,322.77;597.98,138.70" z_order="0">
    </points>
  </image>

I followed the tutorial correctly, and it turns out that a small portion of the files were working properly as I see 99/~400 files working...

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess, but can you try changing the element **<box label="FullBody"...** to**<box="FullBody"...**?. Because if you put attention to the library's code that you're using the **getElementsByTagName** asks for "box" not for "box label"

Comment: sure! i marked it solved but don't have enough points to upvote lol

Comment: Hahahaha Don't worry xD, I'm glad it's solved